# How to append a string to a URL in Swift?

Tags: swift, filesystems

Given a name of a file like this:

`let fileName = "example.jpg"`

I am grabbing the URL of this directory using a helper function, which returns the URL to me:

`let imagesURL = getURL()`

How can I append the string `fileName` to the `imagesURL` such that it returns something like this:

`/path/to/images/dir/example.jpg`

How do I get it in both String and URL format?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This gives you a new URL with the fileName appended:

```
let appended = imagesURL.appendingPathComponent(fileName)
```

And this converts it back to a string:

```
let strVersion = appended.absoluteString //full URL
let strVersion2 = appended.path //path only
```

Comment: This will result in issues - If imageURL is `http://example.com`, then after `appendingPathComponent(fileName)`, it becomes `http:/example.com`

Comment: @BenLu Not sure what you mean -- `URL(string: "http://example.com")!.appendingPathComponent("index.html")` = `http://example.com/index.html` -- try running it in a playground.

Answer (score 2):

`url.appendingPathComponent(fileName)`

has been deprecated, use

`url.appending(path: filename)` instead.

Answer (score 0):

`appendingPathComponent(fileName)` has been deprecated and if you need to use with earlier versions, then use the #available attribute

```
if #available(iOS 16, *) {
    url.appending(path: fileName)
}
else {
    url.appendingPathComponent(fileName)
}
```